# How to see details (e.g. inner exception) of unhanded exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unhandled-exception

In visual studio if exception is unhanded and studio cannot find source code that caused it, screen like this will be shown:

[image]

And that's ok. Let's say I don't need the code, but how can I at least see some exception info except type and message? Inner exception would be helpful for example.

**Edit**: As suggested in @victor-alexandru-papa's answer if "Break when thrown" for Common Language Runtime Exceptions is checked, it will indeed show more info about exception. (in my case `break mode` was caused by exception in not awaited task).

Wanted to do this edit to add some screenshots of what happens. So, as you can see, new `View details` button appears, which actually shows details of the exception. Also I can see stack now and state of my application when exception was thrown.

[image]

Comment: IIRC you can just "continue execution," and the exception will bubble up to a part of your code where the normal Exception Thrown dialog will be shown, which will allow you to observe the inner exception.

Comment: Does *Copy Details* give you more information?

Comment: "continue execution" terminates the application, "Copy Details" just copies what's displayed on the screen (exception type and message)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try going to Debug, Windows, Exception Settings, and check the box under "Break when thrown" for Common Language Runtime Exceptions.